# NSMenu and NSStatusItem action wont work together

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem

The button attached to NSStatusItem is not sending calls to its target selector.

I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. I believe its something to do with the button.action line.

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)
let popover = NSPopover()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    if let button = statusItem.button{
        button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("StatusBar"))
        button.action = #selector(someAction(_:)) //need help here

    }
    popover.contentViewController = QuotesViewController.freshController()
    constructMenu();

}

@objc func someAction(_ sender: Any?){
    print("working");
}
```

i was following this tutorial - [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165853/menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps-macos)

**Edit**

This process of setting actions workes for all of the NSMenuItems that I have. I just still the issue with the NSStatusItem.

**Edit 2**

The code displayed I believe is correct, I now think there's another problem somewhere else.

**Edit 3 Answer**

> "If the status item has a menu set, the action is not sent to the target when the status item is clicked; instead, the click causes the menu to appear."- [appledev NSStatusItem.action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem/1531580-action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "If the status item has a menu set, the action is not sent to the target when the status item is clicked; instead, the click causes the menu to appear."- [apple dev NSStatusItem.action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem/1531580-action)

Comment: @cheesey I've just worked the project. I think there is no problem in function and assign of `button.action.` Does your `EventMonitor` work well ? Or can you see icon well?

Comment: hm, that's weird I get the icon but I don't get the console log I think your right that this piece of code is right there must just be another bug somewhere.

Comment: @cheesey it can be another bug, I've installed and tried several work possibities, but I've printed all the time.

Comment: found the bug there seems to be a problem with my NSMenu I just tried removing that code and testing and it worked.

Comment: so, the bug was in the `constructMenu` function, glad to hear.

Comment: can you change your answer so it reflects the answer I found

Comment: The documentation is of the deprecated `action` of the status item. This is not the action of the button.

Comment: @elia The link is broken.  Is there another source for this?  There's no reference to this on the [updated page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428956-action?language=objc#discussion)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically assign and show the menu property to the button as needed. You'll need to implement the NSMenu menuDidClose method

```
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[self.statusItem.button sendActionOn: (NSLeftMouseUpMask|NSRightMouseUpMask)];
[self.statusItem.button setAction: @selector(statusItemClicked:)];

-(IBAction) statusItemClicked: (id) sender
{
    NSEvent *currentEvent = [NSApp currentEvent];

    // Right click conditions
    if  ((([currentEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) == NSControlKeyMask) ||
        (([currentEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) == NSCommandKeyMask) ||
        (([currentEvent modifierFlags] & NSRightMouseUpMask) == NSRightMouseUpMask) ||    
        (([currentEvent modifierFlags] & NSRightMouseDownMask) == NSRightMouseDownMask) ||
        ([currentEvent type] == NSRightMouseDown) ||
        ([currentEvent type] == NSRightMouseUp))
    {
        [self showStatusMenu: self];
    }
    else
    {
        // do something besides showing the menu    
    }    
}

-(IBAction) showStatusMenu: (id) sender
{
    self.statusItem.menu = self.statusMenu;
    [self.statusItem.button performClick:nil];
}


-(void) menuDidClose : (NSMenu *) someMenu
{
    if (someMenu == self.statusMenu)
    {
            // re-configure statusitem
            self.statusItem.menu = nil;
            [self.statusItem.button sendActionOn: (NSLeftMouseUpMask|NSRightMouseUpMask)];
            [self.statusItem.button setAction: @selector(statusItemClicked:)];
    }
}
```